# Why so many designs of Chinese carrier-based fighter aircraft?

Tags: military, aircraft-carrier, china

I'm quite confused about all the carrier-based fighter aircraft projects in China. Could you help me determine which are the different acronyms (same of different?).

According to wikipedia, there are three possible aircrafts aboard the most recent Chinese air carrier:

- Shenyang J-15, which is already in service aboard Liaoning
- Chengdu J-20
- Shenayang J-31

But looking in the internet, I also found the [J-21](https://eurasiantimes.com/after-j-20-chinas-j-21-carrier-capable-stealth-fighter-aircraft-gets-ready-to-challenge-us-f-35-jets/) that looks like an extension of the J-20. And there is also the newly shown, stealthy, J-35.

Are all those designs similar? What are the differences and the advantages of each of them, since having three diffferent types of aircraft aboard a single carrier is not good idea (speaking about maintenance)?

Comment: Did you know the Ford class aircraft carriers carry more than 8 types of aircraft?

Comment: @RonBeyer I did not know and fast check on internet does not give the type of aircraft. Is it 8 types of fighter aircraft or do you include recon, strike...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking here. The J-15 is a reverse-engineered SU-33, ie a 4 gen fighter which is expected to be in use until the J-20 and/or J-31 (both are 5th gen) will be available. If you are asking for specific differences between the 3, then skimming through the wikipedia articles on each should provide more than enough information (which I presume any one that will attempt to answer this question will do anyway)

Comment: Your question didn't focus on fighter aircraft, as far as I know, the Ford can handle all Navy aircraft including the F-18, E/A-18, and F-35.

Comment: @RonBeyer, from a launch and recovery standpoint the 18s might as well be considered a common airframe.  So I’m struggling to find eight.

Comment: @MichaelHall by that logic C-2 and E-2 would also be pretty much one and the same 

Comment: @Jpe61 - No, those two are completely different airframes.  The E/A and E/F are different only in the equipment they carry and their mission.  Regardless, with the demise of the Tomcat, Viking, Prowler and Intruder, carrier air wings have become very homogenous in appearance.  And I can’t come up with eight…

Comment: @MichaelHall i thought you were referring to Hornet vs. Super Hornet. C-2 and E-2 share wings & powerplants, prolly other parts and systems also, and from launch and recovery standpoint they are quite similar.

Comment: @Jpe61, yeah, sorry I didn't make it more clear.  I can't fathom why the Navy kept the 18 designation for a completely different airframe that is only visually similar to its predecessor.  But, it may be useful to share what carriers consider "similar", at least from a recovery standpoint.  There are 3 critical parameters that need to be met to safely catch an airplane: 1. Arresting gear setting for the max landing weight; 2. Minimum recovery headwind; 3. Lens setting to accommodate airframe differences in hook-to-eye distance.  Between the E2 and C2, all three parameters are different.

Comment: @RonBeyer I edited to make it clearer: it focuses of on fighter aircraft of course since I gave examples of fighter aircraft only

Comment: @Jpe61 the point for Ford-class is that F-18 is for fighting, F-18 super hornet is the new generation and is supposed to replace F-18, EF-18 is for electronic warfare, and F-35 is like "breaking through" a generation. So the fact that there are in the carrier group is explained. For CHinese examples, similare reasons could apply but the *actual* use on a carrrier is not sure given parcellar information available

Answer (score 4):

First, the J-15 is a 4th generation multirole fighter, the western counterpart for it woud be the F/A 18E. While it is still in production and fully capable, it lacks, first and foremost, the stealth properties of 5th gen fighters such as the J-20 and the J-31. The latter two being considerably more modern can be assumed to generally outperform the J-15 by a considerable margin.

The distinction between J-20 and J-31 is their primary roles: J-20 is an air supremacy fighter such as F-22, while J-31 is designed as a multirole fighter, such as the F-35.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation of differences. Are they all planned to enter carrier service? Because for example the F-22 is not on carrier service

Comment: It is my understanding that current J-20 is not carrier capable. I gathered by the info supplied by you in the question that it might be 

Comment: Space is a premium on a carrier so a multi-role fighter is much preferred than single role J-20. This is why Russia retired Su-33 and US retired F-14. So from the very beginning J-20 wasn't designed to be carrier-capable like F-35 or F-14 was. As for J-31 I think it's more for the politics: deploying J-31 on carriers will cause the neighbors to deploy lots of F-35 to counter-balance, which isn't a favorable outcome for China.